# CSS - Show only the last li of the second ul

Tags: css

Given the following html code:

```
<header>
<ul>
<li>Text1a</li>
<li>Text2a</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Text1b</li>
<li>Text2b</li>
</ul>
</header>
```

How can I show only the last li of the second ul (Text2b) without using any id/class?
Thanks.

P.S.: I'm using this css, but it doesn't work:

```
header li:not(:last-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Please also add the css you are using that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found *the solution* (!):

```
header :not(:last-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

Other solutions:

```
header ul:first-of-type, header ul:last-of-type :first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

Or

```
header :first-child, header ul:last-of-type :first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

**Update (2020/04/18)**

Check out this tool, it can be useful:
https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester

Answer (score 2):

First, set `ul > li` to `display: none`

Second, use [`nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) to select from the correct  `ul` and `li`, and override the `display` property for only that element

```css
ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul:nth-of-type(2) li:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li>Text1a</li>
    <li>Text2a</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Text1b</li>
    <li>Text2b</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: ul:first-of-type, ul:last-of-type :first-child {
  display: none;
} ?

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Yes, that also works; It's pretty much the inverse of how I've done it

Comment: Thanks for your answer.